# Преобразование аргументов функции

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

alert(sum('1', '2')); // Как '1' и '2' преобразовать в число? 
// Ответ должен быть 3 а не 12))
```

Comment: `return Number(a) + Number(b);`

Comment: Милорд, благодарю Вас)))

Comment: можно поставить `+` перед `a` и `b`.то есть результат будет  `+a + +b`; Это просто еще один способ

Comment: а для чего вообще цифра в кавычках ?

Comment: Просто хотел узнать, как строку преобразовать в число)))

Comment: А если надо будет преобразовать в строку, то тут есть аналогичные символы типа + ?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/type-conversions

Comment: Спасибо сир Максим, я уже понял)))

Comment: А про `!!value` для boolean забыли

Answer (score 1):

Так в число

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return +a + +b;
};

console.log(sum('1', '2'));
```

Или так в число

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
};

console.log(sum('1', '2'));
```

В строку:

```js
function str(a, b) {
  return a.toString() + b.toString();
};

console.log(str(1, 2));
```

В строку ещё:

```js
function str(a, b) {
  return String(a) + String(b);
};

console.log(str(1, 2));
```

В строку ещё*:

```js
function str(a, b) {
  return ''+a + ''+b;
};

console.log(str(1, 2));
```

Comment: А если надо будет преобразовать в строку, то тут есть аналогичные символы типа + ?

Comment: @Black_Viper, нет, есть метод `.toString()`

Comment: @Black_Viper есть `+''`, с еденытцой: `1 + ''`